# Is there any way I set chcp 65001( utf8) to specific windows Application?

Tags: c#, windows, encoding, utf-8

There is global settings which is when we enable beta : UTF8 UNICODE support in windows, which makes all languages encoding compatible

I want to make one of my application to honor this setting, is this possible ? it is c# application or any manifest file would work?

Comment: How do you expect this setting to work if it only applied to one application? If such application sent its UTF-8 ansi string to another application, what would happen? Why do you want to enable it for a C# app that is Unicode to begin with and this setting does not apply to it?